# Using the C18 compiler on Mac OS X

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm currently in a microcontrollers class, one where we use the PIC18F4550 and must use the C18 compiler (something Windows oriented and used for grading). I'm trying to install this on Mac OS X, and am running into difficulties.

I can't find a valid C18 compiler that works on Mac OS X. Instead, I find a XC8 compiler, which Microchip says is a complete replacement. But, when I try to compile the code below, it gives me an error, and this code is widely used in my class.

```
#pragma interrupt low_isr       // both lines generate errors
_asm goto low_isr _endasm
```

Yes, I have found a [C18 compiler,](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014) but it's only for Windows. Despite how hard I search, I can only find the XC8 compiler. [Online forums](http://www.microchip.com.edgekey.net/forums/m698627-print.aspx) indicate that the C18 compiler for Mac OSX has been taken offline.

Comment: Post the errors.

Comment: Can't you install a virtual machine?

Comment: They're just simple syntax errors. It's `#pragma foo`, the error is `foo unexpected`.

Answer (score 3):

In the new XC8 compiler, you can define a low priority interrupt routine like this:

```
void interrupt low_priority ISR (void)
{
 ...
}
```

Further reading: [MPLAB® XC8 C Compiler User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf)

Comment: I would do this, and I would to simply run my program. I can't because of grading.

Answer (score 2):

Ohhhh C18...how I love you!  Although I have no complaints on xc8 either.

You would be hard pressed to find a simple way of installing the C18 compiler on OSX but it CAN be done.  I just installed it on a windows machine and transferred the files onto my mac :P  Yes, it's a sleazy option but it worked!

Okay, so about your interrupt problem.  We don't have your error messages but from looking at your code I think I see what's wrong.  You seem to be missing some things, but I AM making assumptions here.

When you want to add an interrupt on your pic, you need to remember that there are two kinds of interrupts: low priority and high priority.  It is up to you to decide where your peripheral interrupts (like external IO pins) belong.  I'm sure you know this already judging by the fact that you're using a low priority interrupt.  I just wanted to reiterate it.

Now, for the pic18f4550, the low priority vector lies at address 0x18 in memory.  Therefore you need to write a pragma line that looks like this:

```
#pragma code low_vector=0x18
```

Now, you need to define a function prototype that handles your interrupt requests.  Let's call it "low_int_fcn()"

```
void low_int_fcn();
```

Next, we put in the assembly instructions that point to the interrupt function that you made in the previous step:

```
void low_interrupt(){
  _asm GOTO low_int_fcn _endasm
}
```

Then we write

```
#pragma code
#pragma interruptlow low_int_fcn
```

Finally, in your interrupt function, write the code that needs to be executed when your interrupt triggers.  For example:

```
void low_int_fcn(){
  if(INTCON3bits.INT2IF == 1){
     //do stuff
     INTCON3bits.INT2IF = 0;  // Clear the interrupt flag
  }
}
```

Remember to enable interrupts in your config ie:

```
#pragma config IESO=ON
```

and you should be good to go!  I know this was a long winded answer and you probably knew a bunch of what I said already but I had a lot of trouble on this myself in the past and wanted to make sure you got at least a pretty good grasp of it.

BTW if you don't know already, in MPLabX, go to Help>Help Contents and you can find a wealth of documentation on C18/xc8... compilers and even examples!  You can find an interrupt example under Language Tools>C18 Toolchain>MPLab C Compiler for PIC18>Language Specifics>Pragmas>#pragma interruptlow.

It is SO worth it to read the documentation!  Hope this helped!

Comment: This C file was given to me by the professor, and other students could compile it, so it's not missing anything. I'm installing Windows as a virtual machine to make things easier.